# Where is my logfile of crontab?

Tags: cron

No `/var/log/cron`, no `/var/log/cron.log` on my Debian 7. Where is my logfile of crontab?

```
ls /var/log/cron*
ls: cannot access /var/log/cron*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think on `debian` `cron` writes logs in `/var/log/syslog`.
If your system depends on `rsyslog`or `syslogd` you can check and uncomment either in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or `/etc/syslog.conf` for line:

```
# cron.* /var/log/cron.log
```

and then restart services.

If your system depends on `systemd` for example you can check with following command:

```bash
journalctl _COMM=cron
```

or

```bash
journalctl _COMM=cron --since="date" --until="date"
```

For date format you can check [`journalctl`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html).

Comment: no /etc/rsyslog.con and  /etc/syslog.conf in my debian7.

Comment: fot the first file it is a typo should be /etc/rsyslog.conf if you are not with systemd.

Comment: what about `sudo journalctl --since yesterday -u cron.service`? What is `_COMM`?

Comment: @dashesy `_COMM` filters log entries by the name of the log-emitting executable. However, at least on some systems that executable is actually named `crond`. Thus, you have to use `_COMM=crond` on those. With `-u cron.service` (or rather `-u crond.service` or the shorter `-u crond`) you only get a subset of job execution logs - at least on some systems. For example, on Fedora 38 I don't see the logs of non-root cron jobs and even the root ones are incomplete when filtering by `-u crond.service`.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is not tagged debian and appears in fedora searches as well, here is how to check for recent (systemd-based) fedora:

```bsh
sudo systemctl status crond
```

Typical output

```bsh
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-09-29 16:09:21 CEST; 47min ago
 Main PID: 1167 (crond)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 2.8M
      CPU: 948ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           └─1167 /usr/sbin/crond -n

Sep 29 16:09:21 ncelrnd0216 systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
Sep 29 16:09:21 ncelrnd0216 crond[1167]: (CRON) STARTUP (1.5.4)
Sep 29 16:09:21 ncelrnd0216 crond[1167]: (CRON) INFO (Syslog will be used instead of sendmail.)
Sep 29 16:09:21 ncelrnd0216 crond[1167]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 31% if used.)
Sep 29 16:09:21 ncelrnd0216 crond[1167]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
```

and `all` the logs with

```bsh
journalctl --unit crond -n all
```

Comment: On Fedora 38 such a log is incomplete, i.e. job execution logs from non-root users is excluded and many CMEND lines of root jobs are missing. Whereas filtering by `_COMM=crond` includes them. See also [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/750313/1131).

Answer (score 4):

By default the output from `crontab` jobs are sent to the local email address of the owning user. for example: The `crontab` output for `aUser` on host `www.aDomain.com` would be sent to `aUser@www.aDomain.com`. The system uses  its default mailer to accomplish the task.

You can divert this output to an alternate email address by adding a `MAILTO` statement within the crontab file. For example:

```bash
# Mail any output to myuser@gmail.com, no matter whose crontab this is
MAILTO=myuser@gmail.com
# Run the following command ten minutes after midnight, every day
10 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/aJob.sh
```

Be careful when using an external email address to receive crontab logs. Frequently sent messages may get caught in a spam filter. You would then have to mark the messages as **Not Spam** for services like Yahoo, HotMail, or Gmail.

An alternate solution would be to redirect the output of your crontab commands to a file of your choice. In the example below the `stdout` and `stderr` output is sent to `/tmp/aJob.log`. This method eliminates the possibility of an email message being sent.

```bash
# Run the following command ten minutes after midnight, every day
10 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/aJob.sh >> /tmp/aJob.log 2>&1
```

Another alternative is to send `stderr` logs to email and `stdout` logs to a file. In this case you get alerted by email when your `crontab` commands generate unexpected error messages. The difference with the previous example is that `2>&1` is removed to allow `stderr` output to go to the console and therefore to email.

```bash
# Mail any output to myuser@gmail.com, no matter whose crontab this is
MAILTO=myuser@gmail.com    
# Run the following command ten minutes after midnight, every day
10 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/aJob.sh >> /tmp/aJob.log
```

Read more [crontab tables](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) and [crontab command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)

Comment: OP is likely referring to the logging of the Cron daemon itself, whereas you are referring to the stdout/stderr handling of cron jobs. When a cron job time specification matches, a Cron  daemon logs its job execution, i.e. even when it was successful. For example, [cronie](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie) logs CMD/CMDEND including full command lines and user name. By comparing matching CMD/CMDEND lines you can compute the job's run time.

Comment: I think in classic cron daemons there actually was no idea of and no need for logging the operation of the cron daemon itself, as anything it did was to start a command on a time based schedule. So for diagnostics of a working cron daemon it is best to simply schedule a job and check it's output in some very near future. That way you also train to modify the crontab. But in the end you are right: The question is about the cron daemon itself. I just never had a use for that.

Answer (score 1):

Check `MAILTO`'s inbox: `/var/spool/mail/root`. The cron job's execution log will remain there.

Answer (score 1):

2020: Google brought me for something similar.

With distros that are using systemd, there is no more `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/cron`.

With systemd, the journald daemon handles logging.

To see if cron is running your scripts and to follow the log, use;

```
journalctl -u cron.service -f
```

Comment: And in case you are using another cron tool, such as cronie in my case, then the right command is "journalctl -u cronie.service -f". Remove "-f" (follow) to see if you have received any logs until now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron file in `/var/log` and restart the `syslog` service:

```
# touch /var/log/cron
# systemctl restart rsyslog
```

then check for logs.

Answer (score 0):

On a journald enabled Linux system you can view the cron job execution logs like this:

```
# journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=CROND
```

Example output:

```
[..]
Jul 01 06:23:02 example.org CROND[143073]: (backupuser) CMD (/usr/local/bin/backup.sh)
Jul 01 06:24:36 goedel.lru.li CROND[143045]: (restic) CMDEND (/usr/local/bin/backup.sh)
[..]
```

Alternatively, you can filter on the executable name of your cron daemon, which is less to type (unless your cron daemon's executable is named differently):

```
journalctl _COMM=crond
```

---

NB: `journalctl -u crond` also includes some job logs, but at least on some systems it's incomplete, i.e. non-root user jobs are excluded and many CMDEND lines are missing. (e.g. I'm observing this with systemd-253.5-1.fc38.x86_64)

---

You can combine the above filters with other predicates, e.g. to to just list the logs of a certain user after a certain point in time:

```
journalctl --since '2023-07-01 08:23' SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=CROND _AUDIT_LOGINUID=666
```

Or to jump to the end of the log:

```
journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=CROND -e
```